# How to create this 3 button in react Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create this 3 button but I can't create third button because I don't know how use multiple useState in React Js.

This is my code :

```
  const ShowOrNot = () => {
    const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
    const [showPreview , setShowPreview] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className="col-12">
            {showForm ? (
                <div className={"content-send-form-wrapper"} id="scrollbar-style">
                    <div className={"content-send-form-header"}>
                        <div className={"content-send-form-header-title"}>
                           
                        </div>
                        <h2>
                            New Upload
                        </h2>
                        <div className={"content-send-form-close-btn"}>
                            <button onClick={() => setShowForm(false)} className={"close-modal-btn"}>
                                Close <span></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form className={"mt-3 content-send-form-data register-teacher-inputs-box "}>
                        <Row>
                            <div className={"col-lg-6 col-12 mt-4"}>
                                <label
                                    htmlFor={"name"} className={" text-right"}>
                                    <span>*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder={"عنوان"}
                                       name={""} required="true"
                                       // value={this.name}
                                       // onChange={this.onChange}
                                       onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "عنوان"}
                                       onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className={"col-lg-6 col-12 mt-4"}>
                                <label
                                    htmlFor={"country"} className={" text-right"}>
                                    <span>*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder={"دسته بندی"}
                                       name={"country"}
                                       // value={this.country}
                                       // onChange={this.onChange}
                                       required="true"
                                       onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "دسته بندی"}
                                       onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <div className="col-12 mt-3">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor={"name"} className={"label-full-size text-right"}>
                                    <span>*</span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder={"خلاصه توضیحات"}
                                       name={""} required="true"
                                       // value={this.name}
                                       // onChange={this.onChange}
                                       onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "خلاصه توضیحات"}
                                       onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <div className="col-12 mt-3">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor={"name"} className={"label-full-size text-right textarea-label"}>
                                    <span>*</span>
                                </label>
                                <textarea  className="video-text-form form-control" placeholder={"متن ویدیو"}
                                       name={""} required="true"
                                       // value={this.name}
                                       // onChange={this.onChange}
                                       onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "متن ویدیو"}
                                       onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <div className="col-12 mt-3 video-upload-input-btn">
                                <VideoUpload />
                            </div>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-3">
                              <PosterUpload />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-3">
                                <CoverUpload />
                            </div>
                        </Row>
                    </form>
               
                    {showPreview ? (
                        <div>
                            show preview
                        </div>
                    ) : (<Row>
                        <div className="col-lg-8 col mt-3">
                            <button className="preview-send-data-btn" onClick={function(event){ setShowPreview(true); setShowForm(true)}}>
                               Preview
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-4 col mt-3">
                            <button className="draft-send-data-btn">
                               Draft
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </Row>)}

                </div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <button className="upload-content-btn w-100" onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}>
                        <span className="ml-2">
                     
                    </span>New Upload </button>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<ShowOrNot />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I want when click on Preview button showFrom not show and other form that in showPreview display instead. My problem is not about CSS and just I don't know how to use useState like before steps I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example *Preview* inside of *Form*, so if you hide *form* *preview* will be hidden too.

You need to properly organize components so your code will be easy to read and understand. Without that you can not solve any complex enough task.

Can start like this.

```
const ShowOrNot = () => {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(false);
  const [formHidden, setFormHidden] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="col-12">
      {!showForm ? (
        <ShowFormButton onClick={() => setShowForm(true)} />
      ) : undefined}

      {showForm ? (
        <div className={'content-send-form-wrapper'} id="scrollbar-style">
          <div className={'content-send-form-header'}>
            <div className={'content-send-form-header-title'}></div>
            <h2>New Upload</h2>

            <HideFormButton
              onClick={() => {
                setShowForm(false);
              }}
            />
          </div>

          {!formHidden ? <MyForm /> : undefined}

          {!showPreview ? (
            <ShowPreviewButton
              onClick={() => {
                setShowPreview(true);
                setFormHidden(true);
              }}
            />
          ) : undefined}
          {showPreview ? (
            <div>
              Preview
              <SendButton
                onClick={() => {
                  setFormHidden(false);
                  setShowPreview(false);
                  setShowForm(false);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          ) : undefined}
        </div>
      ) : undefined}
    </div>
  );
};

function SendButton({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className=" w-100" onClick={onClick}>
        <span className="ml-2"></span>Send
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ShowFormButton({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="upload-content-btn w-100" onClick={onClick}>
        <span className="ml-2"></span>New Upload{' '}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ShowPreviewButton({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <Row>
      <div className="col-lg-8 col mt-3">
        <button className="preview-send-data-btn" onClick={onClick}>
          Preview
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-4 col mt-3">
        <button className="draft-send-data-btn">Draft</button>
      </div>
    </Row>
  );
}

function HideFormButton({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <div className={'content-send-form-close-btn'}>
      <button onClick={onClick} className={'close-modal-btn'}>
        <span>Close</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

function MyForm() {
  return (
    <form
      className={'mt-3 content-send-form-data register-teacher-inputs-box '}
    >
      <Row>
        <div className={'col-lg-6 col-12 mt-4'}>
          <label htmlFor={'name'} className={' text-right'}>
            <span>*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={'عنوان'}
            name={''}
            required="true"
            // value={this.name}
            // onChange={this.onChange}
            onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'عنوان')}
            onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={'col-lg-6 col-12 mt-4'}>
          <label htmlFor={'country'} className={' text-right'}>
            <span>*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={'دسته بندی'}
            name={'country'}
            // value={this.country}
            // onChange={this.onChange}
            required="true"
            onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'دسته بندی')}
            onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
          />
        </div>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <div className="col-12 mt-3">
          <label htmlFor={'name'} className={'label-full-size text-right'}>
            <span>*</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={'خلاصه توضیحات'}
            name={''}
            required="true"
            // value={this.name}
            // onChange={this.onChange}
            onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'خلاصه توضیحات')}
            onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
          />
        </div>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <div className="col-12 mt-3">
          <label
            htmlFor={'name'}
            className={'label-full-size text-right textarea-label'}
          >
            <span>*</span>
          </label>
          <textarea
            className="video-text-form form-control"
            placeholder={'متن ویدیو'}
            name={''}
            required="true"
            // value={this.name}
            // onChange={this.onChange}
            onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'متن ویدیو')}
            onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
          />
        </div>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <div className="col-12 mt-3 video-upload-input-btn">
          <VideoUpload />
        </div>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-3">
          <PosterUpload />
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-3">
          <CoverUpload />
        </div>
      </Row>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ShowOrNot />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use setState like this code

```
setShowForm(false) or setShowForm(true)
```

and

```
setShowPreview(true) or setShowPreview(false)
```